# What do you call money earned through unethical sources?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, money

> Money/Assets/Property that is earned through unethical sources is
>   called ?

Money that is earned through bad sources like corrupted politics, corrupted business, ransom money, stolen or theft money. What is such money called? 
Is it bad money, black money. What is **one** particular name for it?

Comment: It is called *wealth.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan wealth is the general name for good or bad money. btw nice pick

Comment: bribe/ black mmoney?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It is often called: ***[dirty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dirty)*** money:

> - Profit from the sale of narcotics, prostitution, guns, or other illegal activities. Money that needs to be laundered.
> - money obtained illegally.

(AHD)

Comment: Well, how about a suggestion for adding more to this answer: it's worth noting that the process of getting rid of *dirty money* to get money that is more safely usable is called *money laundering*, literally cleaning the money.

Comment: @tchrist While I agree with your comment, I feel compelled to point out that your first sentence, as written, might be read by a user unfamiliar with this site's policies as contradicting your second. You should clarify that the reason why pure-citation answers are inappropriate for a question-and-answer site is that they don't add value that distinguishes us from a commonly-available reference, and thereby reduces the utility of the site as a source of information not available in those sources.

Comment: Regarding "laundering" of dirty money, it is the passing of money gained through illicit means through banks, services, and asset purchases to _confuse_ attempts to trace a particular bit of cash or an asset back to the original crime. Laundered money is still technically an illicit gain, but after enough scrubbing, might not be legally seizable.

Comment: You can launder money through gambling. 1. Earn 1 mil$ illicitly. 2. Bet $1 mil, win $500k back. Be $500k down, but it's all now legit money and virtually unconnectable with the original sum. Just pointing this out, not giving advice...

Answer (score 79):

From dictionary.com...

> [**ill-gotten gains**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ill-gotten+gains) *Benefits obtained in an evil manner or by dishonest means, as in They duped their senile uncle into leaving them a fortune and are now enjoying their ill-gotten gains . [Mid-1800s]*

I think one reasonably consistent distinction between this and @Josh61's suggestion is...

> *dirty money* was usually already "illegal, hot, immoral" before the current "owner" got his hands on it. It passes through a "chain" of criminals all involved in illegal/immoral activities.
>
> *ill-gotten gains* has no such "chain of illegal activity" connotations. Often it's just wealth "improperly" acquired by the current owner by a single illegal/immoral action.

Comment: I've never heard of *dirty money* as necessarily having previous criminal owners. *Ill-gotten gains* is certainly a good suggestion, but I don't think your distinction holds.

Comment: @KRyan: If you don't buy my distinction I can hardly change your mind, but I would point out that *dirty **money*** explicitly focusses on the actual "filthy lucre" - so it's easier to see it as some particular amount of illicit cash being passed from person to person in a chain of criminality. Whereas ***ill-gotten** gains* focusses more on *how the current "owner" got it* - which is more easily connected to a single illegal/immoral act resulting in a one-off "gain".

Comment: I agree that *ill-gotten gains* would be an odd choice to call money you didn't gain yourself through ill means. But I don't think anyone would find it odd to call money you got from a bank heist *dirty money*.

Comment: @KRyan: I only said mine was a ***reasonably** consistent distinction*. I've no idea how many of the upvotes for this answer are specifically agreeing with my contention that such a distinction is often recognised. Perhaps *no-one* except me recognises it, and all the upvotes are just because ["ill-gotten gains" has always been more common than "dirty money"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ill-gotten+gains%2Cdirty+money&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cill%20-%20gotten%20gains%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdirty%20money%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: ill gotten gains .. nice one.

Comment: If I were answering this question, I'd have answered with "Ill gotten gains" but when I saw "dirty money", I immediately thought that was also an excellent answer. As to the distinction made by Fumble, I can see his point, but I'm not sure the distinction is always there. However; there are certainly times, where "dirty money" fits much better than "Ill.." as Fumble himself points out. +1

Comment: @TecBrat: Once again, I am ***not*** claiming my distinction is "always there". I'm saying that to the extent anyone might ever wish to assign the two different terms to *money which passes through the hands of numerous different people engaged in a chain of immoral activity* on the one hand, and *money improperly acquired by one person through an activity that's not part of such a chain*, I think it's reasonable to assume most people would assign the two terms the way I have.

Comment: Dirty money suggest the money itself is tainted due to previous transactions it was involved in.  Ill-gotten gains suggests that the person who currently holds the money is tainted due to the transaction they received it in. The difference is whether the person is bad, or the money itself is bad. It's possible to receive dirty money without you being implicated as a bad person.  It's possible to gain money through bad means without necessarily dirtying the money. It's possible to have both in a given situation. The distinction is whether the money itself is considered tainted, or the person.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You might want to clarify that the "usually" in your answer shouldn't be read as "practically always" in the text of your answer, as these comments will be cleared away eventually. At present, the wording is being misinterpreted; I, myself, was decided against upvoting until I read the clarifications in this comment thread.

Comment: @user867: I suppose that means you think my distinction applies so rarely you take issue with my use of *usually*. In the context of an assertion I'd already qualified as only "reasonably consistent", you should assume *usually = [probably] more than half the time*. Adam's comment above argues indirectly for my point, which I'm quite happy to stand by *as phrased*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I have no strong opinion on how commonly the distinction applies, and I'd say that your wording is not incorrect - just that it's easy to misinterpret, as evidenced by those of us who misinterpreted it. Given that these comments do get cleaned up periodically, clarifying your answer may save you from having to explain again to someone else a few years from now.

Comment: @user867: If the comments remain *relevant* to the question/answer, I expect they'll be left untouched. So I'll just announce to the housekeeping mods of the future that I think it's relevant to both this and Josh61's answer to point out that [the "real" OED](http://www.oed.com/) doesn't even *list* this definition of "dirty money" (they only have the *additional payment made to workers doing a particularly unpleasant/dirty job*). There's always more you *could* add to an answer, but you have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When there's a long thread of comments debating a particular point, though, it's not uncommon for mods to assume it's a comment war where the same points are reiterated without reaching a conclusion, and easier still to delete it without reading through the whole presumably-repetitive thing. As I write this, it is the thirteenth comment on the answer; I suspect a "tl;dr" reaction is becoming a definite possibility.

Comment: I was also going to upvote until I read about the "distinction". Even after reading these comments, I'm not going to. The comments aren't part of the answer.

Answer (score 32):

A classic cliche for describing money "earned" in this manner is *filthy lucre* or just *lucre*:

> **filthy lucre**  Money; money or other material goods acquired through unethical or dishonorable means, dirty money. (See [The Free Dictionary's entry under money](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/money).)

**Lucre** itself has taken on the shameful meaning imparted to it originally by the adjective *filthy*:

> Word History: When William Tyndale translated *aiskhron kerdos*, "shameful gain" (Titus 1:11), as filthy lucre in his edition of the Bible, he was tarring the word lucre for the rest of its existence. But we cannot lay the pejorative sense of lucre completely at Tyndale's door. He was merely a link, albeit a strong one, in a process that had begun long before with respect to the ancestor of our word, the Latin word *lucrum*, "material gain, profit." This process was probably controlled by the inevitable conjunction of profit, especially monetary profit, with evils such as greed. In Latin *lucrum* also meant "avarice," and in Middle English *lucre*, besides meaning "monetary gain, profit," meant "illicit gain." (See [The Free Dictionary: lucre](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lucre).)

Comment: that's what I would have answered. *filthy lucre* is itself a calque on Latin *turpe lucrum*.

Comment: This answer is not complete without a [big band](http://youtu.be/dwmIu-3ZA4U?t=18s) reference. (Originally from [*Gold Diggers of 1933*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Diggers_of_1937#Songs)). (But I +1'd cause I listened to the song anyways.)

Comment: I've never heard *filthy lucre* used to mean *ill-gotten gains*. I've only ever heard it used in the sense that lucre is inherently filthy, with *filthy* redundantly appearing in order to allude to the saying, "money is the root of all evil." Interesting how connotations change or get lost.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to **loot and booty**, which are limited, and **dirty money**, which is quite general, I would offer up the more specific **blood money**.

Loot and booty are more specifically for theft or ransacking of a national treasure, such as a tomb filled with gold. Dirty money is quite general and can be used for any illegally or unethically acquired gain.

Blood money is used to describe a situation where one party gains financially at the detriment or even death of another. The winning party then gives money to the hurt party or the next of kin.

In more casual use, I have heard people referring to any money gained through murder or other violent acts as blood money. For example, someone might say that

> The mafia family built their inheritance on blood money.

A similar term is **blood diamond**. Its use is reserved for diamonds that were acquired through violence or harsh mining conditions. Considering that use, with some creativity in the situation, you might prepend any item of value with the word blood to give your audience the impression of acquiring the asset through violence or other dubious means. Jokingly, you could say

> John's promotion was a blood promotion, because he was ruthless in acquiring it.

Other cultures use the term more specifically and even legally. Westernized cultures use it loosely and never legally, as far as I know.

[Wikipedia has an entry on blood money.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_money_(restitution))

Comment: By the same logic and specificity, **drug money** is equally self evident. Blood money however does have usage outside of its literal meaning, which in my experience drug money lacks - it is more restricted in this sense.

Comment: Blood money is also used in societies that have the option of a victim or victims family receiving payment in lieu of other punishments.

Comment: **Booty** seems a good all-purpose term for any sort of unearned gain, from war-looting to lottery-wins. Except for the fact that the gang of idiots formerly known as the human race decided to use the word for sexual purposes. Idiots.  Blood money, aside from being **two** words, suggests mostly extreme cases, especially *The Merchant of Venice*...

Comment: @Kibitzologist Whatever the meaning, I wouldn't mind a healthy share of some booty.

Comment: [Blood diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_diamond) refers to diamonds that finance conflicts, not how they were acquired.

Answer (score 16):

**[Graft](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/graft#graft-2)**. *Graft* is corruption usually through bribery; political favor for political donation.

Comment: It also means gains secured by corruption. Good answer.

Answer (score 8):

Two terms used in British law are "[immoral earnings](http://www.inbrief.co.uk/offences/living-off-immoral-earnings.htm)" and "the [proceeds of crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceeds_of_Crime_Act_2002)".  The former refers specifically to money made through prostitution; the second to any material profit from criminal activity.

Comment: Note that since income from prostitution is taxable then HRMC can be called to task for having income from immoral earnings but personally I would say the two terms have a one to one mapping with parliamentary salary and parliamentary expenses.

Answer (score 3):

The word you're looking for is "[booty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/booty)" or possibly "[loot](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/loot?s=t)"

**Booty -**  From the low german *bute*; A sharing of the spoils of criminality

**Loot -** From the Sanskrit *luṇṭhati*; Something taken by dishonesty

Comment: both of those words have completely different meanings now in the mainstream public.  Loot is just a synonym for any money ("I'm out getting my loot") and, well, booty has a different more common meaning to the masses as well.

Comment: no Loot is specifically things obtained by physically stealing during wars or other civil disturbances.

Comment: @stephenbayer A dual meaning used to advantage by Sara Lorimer in her book *Booty: Girl Pirates on the High Seas*.

Comment: You and I against the world, Richard! PS: Shake your moneymaker!! =]

Answer (score 1):

Black money- income illegally obtained or not declared for tax purposes.

Google the term.

Investopedia says "black money: proceeds, usually received in cash, from underground economic activity. Black money is earned through illegal activity and, as such, is not taxed. Possible sources of black money include drug trafficking, weapons trading, terrorism, prostitution, selling counterfeit or stolen goods and selling pirated versions of copyrighted items such as software and musical recordings."

Comment: I think ***black money*** has little currency outside of Indian English - where I assume it's arisen primarily by extension from the thriving [***black economy*** in India](http://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21573979-banking-scandal-highlights-problem-black-money-india-evasive-action)

Comment: Furthermore this term seems to focus on legality, rather than ethics.

Comment: Money to be spent only at the **black market**...

Comment: @FumbleFingers "little currency" nice pun!

Comment: Hi Fumble - it's odd you would suggest that is InE.  "the black economy" is  used extremely commonly everywhere (just google)

Answer (score 1):

grift.

As in a 'grifter' or 'grifting', money obtained via a swindle.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grifting

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say "MPs Income" - but seriously I would say "Illegitimate Income" - i.e. any income from sources that are not those that are Legitimate.  The other phrase that is often used is "under the counter".

Answer (score 0):

***mucky pelf***

> pelf
>
> (*derogatory*): money or wealth, esp. if dishonestly acquired; lucre
>
> [C14: from Old French pelfre booty; related to Latin pilāre to despoil]
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pelf)
>
> : money; riches; lucre; gain; -- generally conveying the idea of something ill-gotten or worthless. It has no plural.
>
> [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/pelf.html)

[***evil-gotten***](http://www.tokishi.on-rev.com/mwpg64/256compo.txt) gains; [***misbegotten gains***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22misbegotten+gains%22&oq=%22misbegotten+gains%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...2639.5133.0.5978.5.5.0.0.0.0.219.477.0j2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..2.0.0.EYxwEG4lX_k)

> *The price paid for wrongdoing seems rather enticing. The violators are almost encouraged to violate the law because the penalty is so small. The evil-gotten gains are expansive. The sanctions are minuscular.*
>
> [Increasing Criminal Penalties Under the Sherman Antitrust Act: Hearing, Eighth-third Congress, Second Session on H.R. 2237. July 7, 1954](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HQ3MEpaCwmgC&q=%22evil+gotten+gains%22&dq=%22evil+gotten+gains%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8u_30i_zLAhWM5xoKHVJSDPc4ChDoAQg7MAU)
>
> **evil**
>
> *adverb* in an evil, wicked, or offensive way (now only in hyphenated compounds)   ⇒ *evil-hearted*
>
> [Collins American English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/evil)
>
> *Evil gotten, evil spent.*
>
> [Dictionary of English Proverbs and Proverbials](https://books.google.fr/books?id=OrVO3BlJ__AC&pg=PT51&dq=%22evil+gotten+evil+spent%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPmtnus_zLAhWGJhoKHXSmBKkQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22evil%20gotten%20evil%20spent%22&f=false)
>
> **misbegotten**
>
> : unlawfully obtained *misbegotten gains*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misbegotten)