# they would've got away with/would've gotten away with it

Tags: meaning, north-american-english, transatlantic-differences, insular-english, got-gotten

Which is right:

1. They would’ve **got** away with it.
2. They would’ve **gotten** away with it.

I am interested in what we would say in the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, not in the United States of America.

Comment: Unless we're copying Americans, BrE speakers wouldn't use ***gotten*** at all (I know careful AmE speakers distinguish the two, but I forget exactly how).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was about to comment that this is a case where Americans can use either ***got*** or ***gotten***, but this may be my age showing. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+have+gotten+away+with%2Cwould+have+got+away+with&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20have%20gotten%20away%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%20have%20got%20away%20with%3B%2Cc0) shows that the distinction between ***got*** and ***gotten*** is sharpening in this case, and the clear preference today in this phrase is for ***gotten***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Except, as tchrist points out on another post, in the case of *ill-gotten gains*.

Comment: Either phrase would likely lead me to mentally add ".. if it wasn't for those meddling kids"

Comment: @Peter: I thought it was *you* that commented some while ago about a usage distinction based on whether ***got*** related to actual "possession" (so you wouldn't have *gotten scared* by something - I don't know).

Comment: @WS2: Considering it's [my fourth most popular answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/184695/2637) here on ELU, I really should have remembered that! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that's right, *"have got"* means possession, and *"have gotten"* is used everywhere else. I had thought there were some cases where Americans could use either one, but looking at Ngrams, I think I'm wrong ... some Americans are still using *got* for the past participle in all cases, but the number is steadily going down.

Comment: @Peter: So in fact you *could* have ***gotten*** scared if I'd ***got*** a pitchfork and brandished it in your face threateningly?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: right.

Comment: Any one else immediately think of [Scooby-Doo](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=And+I+would+have+gotten+away+with+it+too%2C+if+it+weren%27t+for+you+meddling+kids)?

Comment: FF says 'Unless we're copying Americans, BrE speakers wouldn't use _gotten_ at all'. But there's no law forbidding people ('we'!?) in the UK from doing precisely that. They (/'we') don't get arrested. This whole 'BrE' v 'AmE' analysis masks the true picture. A lot of (yes, I have to call them something) Americanisms are creeping into occasional or even common use in the UK, especially via the media, and such usages must not be termed incorrect.

Comment: Ireland I would say 'would have got' would take first prize.