# What is the verb for earning money though bad ways or illegal?

Tags: verbs

How to say if a person earns lot of money especially in a bad ways or through illegal business. I want to know the verb of earning money through illegally and how can we call such a person.

Comment: Related: [What do you call money earned through unethical sources?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184689/what-do-you-call-money-earned-through-unethical-sources)

Comment: I do not know the verb, but, you could say, *"His earnings were with black money."*

Comment: There are many different types of illegal activity (gambling, embezzling, robbery, narcotics, etc).  Your question is too general.

Comment: @Asker123: that is not idiomatic English.  Perhaps "He earned his money on the black market".

Comment: *The wages of sin* and a *sinner*.

Answer (score 5):

1. I do not know if there is a single verb to satisfy you, but there are several that are identified with the person's specific conduct.

These include embezzling, stealing, extorting, blackmailing, robbing, fencing, counterfeiting, loansharking, and the like.

2. The noun that applies to all of these characters is "Crook".

Comment: +1 for "crook".  We can also say "he's crookéd".

Comment: simplest denotation

Comment: Note that *crook* and *crooked* are informal; the nearest formal equivalent is probably *criminal*.

Answer (score 4):

**scam**(n/v)......is a sneaky or dishonest plan that's meant to con someone.

**scamster**(n).....: a person who deceives people to get their money.

> A scam is basically a hoax dressed up to look like a real business
>   plan, worthwhile invention, or investment idea. Scams are almost
>   always designed to make money for their creators.

- **You can also use the word as a verb**: *"His evil plan was to **scam** people into buying fake tickets to the baseball game."*

**(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/scam)**)**

Comment: +1, In the Indian sub continent , the newspapers are flooded with news on scams and scamsters. http://trak.in/tags/business/2010/11/25/top-10-corruption-scams-scandals-india/

Comment: This is rather specific to money gained by fraud.  For instance, you wouldn't use *scamster* to describe someone who earns money by selling illegal drugs, assuming that his customers actually receive the drugs they pay for.

Answer (score 3):

I might talk of someone's ***ill-gotten gains***. That is, incidentally, one of the few instances in Britain where we use *gotten*.

Answer (score 2):

A good verb that comes to mind, apart from [steal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steal) and [embezzle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/embezzle), is

**[Swindle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swindle#swindle__2)**

> Use deception to deprive (someone) of money or possessions:
>
> *a businessman swindled investors out of millions of pounds*
>
> 1.1 Obtain (money) fraudulently:
>
> *he was said to have swindled £62.5 million from the state-owned cement industry*

---

A person earning money through illegal businesses can be...

a [racketeer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/racketeer#racketeer__2) ,

> A person who engages in dishonest and fraudulent business dealings.

a [fraudster](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fraudster#fraudster__2),

> A person who commits fraud, especially in business dealings.

or a [con artist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/con-artist#con-artist__2)

> A person who cheats or tricks others by persuading them to believe something that is not true:

among others.

(ODO)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two possibilities. The person might be *[sharking](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sharking)*

> *v.intr.* To take advantage of others for personal gain, especially by
>   fraud and trickery. [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

or perhaps *spivving*, from *[spiv](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spiv)*:-

> *n*
>   1. Brit a person who makes a living by underhand dealings or swindling; black marketeer [Collins English Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

Comment: Does "spiv" as a verb really exist?  The only uses I can find online of "spivving" are as an alternative to "spiffing", which is completely different. _(Edit: different in meaning, that is - I see that the etymology is linked.)_

Answer (score 1):

You could call this person a "***hustler***", although it may have different meanings in different contexts. If you say, "He makes his money by ***hustling,***" most people would assume that 'his' profits are ill-gotten.

Answer (score 0):

**Skullduggery**. Dishonest practices carried out in order to trick someone and earn money illegally. ....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a verb, but an adjective that could be used in a sentence.

> **Venal**
>
> adj. Willing to do dishonest things in return for money.
>
> *The judge is known for being **venal***.

[Link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venal)